# Where is the pick list setting type?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-central

According to the documentation, when creating a device template in the IOT Central application portal, there should be a setting type of pick list. I am not seeing this option.

I have tried reloading the window and I have checked in all three application templates.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the documentation you mentioned?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-set-up-template#settings -- i've opened a bug to get the documentation fixed (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34398)

Comment: This issue is fixed and documentation has been updated as per the https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34398

Comment: Since this was a documentation problem and its fixed, may I suggest deleting this question. It won't help anyone else.